# Why is a third-space C on the staff played on the second-string, 1st guitar fret?

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature

I am reading **Classic Guitar for Dummies** by Chappell, Jon; Phillips, Mark. Classical Guitar For Dummies® (p. 83). Wiley. Kindle Edition.

The question comes from a direct statement in the text, which I do not understand.

How should I know exactly that when I see a third-space C on the staff to play the 2nd string, 1st fret C and not the 3rd string, 5th fret C or the 4th string, 10th fret C, for example.

Thank you,

Marla